# Margin around set height and width

Tags: html, css

As the title says I'm looking to add a gap, I know I can do this by setting a different width but I want to do this using margin. It just doesn't work, it pushes the div down (In the jsfiddle is just doesn't add the margin because of height:100%).

Here's a fiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/s31r2af4/

How can I solve this? (No `overflow:auto`)

Comment: either you can increase height of main `div` or `overflow:auto` or just decrease both inner `div` height

Comment: @Bhargav increase height?

Comment: @Bhargav so making height `calc(100% - 20px)` should do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.chat-holder{
  margin:10px;
  height:calc(100% - 20px);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sidebar{
  width:50%;
  height:500px;
  background:purple;
  overflow:overlay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give margin in `%`.

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/s31r2af4/1/

Comment: you have decrease `div` height its not proper

Answer (score 0):

Just use padding instead of margin

```
.chat-holder{
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```